# SQL - Printing a list with a specific data type and date.

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm required to display a list of pets that had an injection during May 2004. I am mean't to show the date of the visit, the pet's name, the type, the breed and the type of treatment. Then I'm required to sort the report by the date of the visit. I have added my SQL command so far below along with the structure of both my pet and visit table. I'm not sure how to proceed from my current SQL command to the one requested from the question.

```
SELECT Visit_Date, Name, Type, Breed, Treatment
FROM visit, pet
WHERE Treatment = 'injection'
ORDER BY Visit_Date;
```

Pet table structure:

```
pet_id, Name, Type, Breed, Gender, Born, owner_id, Notes
```

Example Data:
    P0001, Tiddles, cat, persian, F, 1998, 2, Has a bad temper and scratches you

Visit table structure:

```
visit_id, pet_id, vet_id, Visit_Date, Basic_Cost, Symptom, Treatment
```

Example Data:
    VS01, P0001, V01, 21/04/2004, 23.99, Bitten left ear, Injection

I really hope you can help as I'm not sure how to proceed here. Any help is massively appreciated also note I'm using ms access.

Comment: You need to join tables visit to pet, using an INNER JOIN (i assume) on pet_ID between both

Answer (score 2):

This will help you understanding the join types:
https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

few things:

1. Learn how to join tables using INNER/Outer join syntax
2. Learn about the year() function
3. Learn about the month() function
4. Learn how to alias tables to save typing and improve readability (and use them on all fields so you know what the source table is when the same named column exists in different tables.

.

```
SELECT V.Visit_Date, P.Name, P.Type, P.Breed, V.Treatment
FROM visit V
INNER JOIN  pet P
  on V.Pet_ID = P.Pet_ID 
WHERE V.Treatment = 'injection'
  and month(v.visit_Date) = 5
  and year(V.visit_date) = 2004
ORDER BY V.Visit_Date;
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. I definetley want to read into SQL more after I've completed my tasks. Though I have used join types to a degree before but what is really halting me from advancing is including the date. Because searching by injection is only one part. I need to search for data within may 2004 aswell.

Comment: Date search is there too month/year functions

Comment: Forget my comment about date. Thanks I'll go give this a try.

Comment: I am getting an error when I try and run the command. Syntax error in FROM clause.

Comment: oops missing `on clause`.  guess I need to read up on those joins too :/

Comment: Another issue. The table prints but there is no data.

Answer (score 0):

JOIN with ON `pet_id` is give your expected result. Use [MONTH](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/month.php) and [YEAR](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/date/year.php) function for date filtering.

Also use table alias name for better readability.

```
SELECT V.Visit_Date, P.Name, P.Type, P.Breed, V.Treatment
FROM visit AS V
JOIN pet AS P ON P.pet_id = V.pet_id
WHERE V.Treatment = 'injection' AND MONTH(V.Visit_Date) = 5 AND YEAR(V.Visit_Date) = 2004
ORDER BY V.Visit_Date;
```

Comment: Missed the date requirement (I did too at first) "display a list of pets that had an injection during May 2004."

Comment: @xQbert Yeah missed, now added.